# How can I express Dm using only the notes of C major?

Tags: theory, harmony

I'm a guitarist duo-ing with a 'harp' player whose strings all are notes in the key of C.

In other words, the harp player has the notes  C D E F G A B   available, and no others.

The minor triads available are thus   Am  Dm  Em

We would like to play in (faux) Dm.

That is to say, we want to start and end on Dm, and have Dm feel like home-base.

Since C# is not an available note, he cannot construct an A7 chord to "tonicize" the Dm in the classical way.

So, with Dm  the designated home-base, within the limitations noted, what chords and extensions can be used with good aural results to "go away" from and "come back" to Dm so as to produce a satisfying (though admittedly non-standard) feeling of cadence and resolution?

Comment: A comment, not an answer. All the harp players I play with  - probably a good half a dozen or more - come prepared with a battery of at least half a dozen harps in different keys. Their C harp will play in C (obviously!), and as cross harp in G. And - the really good ones will have a chromatic at hand in order to play any darned note you want them to. And those in between!!

Comment: OP talks about harp with strings. Is it an actual harp (like the Guinness logo) or harmonica/mouth organ (which is called a harp colloquially)?

Comment: It's a custom string instrument.

Answer (score 8):

You're in 'D Dorian' then.  As is plenty of folk music. Centre the melody on D, begin and end on D minor.  Like this:

[image]

You might find the bVII (C major) takes on something of a dominant function.

Don't forget you both have the option of playing contrapuntal (or, indeed, unison) melodies, runs in 3rds (or other intervals) etc. etc.   There's more to music than 'melody and triads'

Comment: Nice to see a question bemoaning the lack of a leading note, rather than one trying to understand how a C# can be allowed in their nice, pure D Dorian scale :-)

Comment: The song example here is wonderful.  Thank you!

I can really hear the home base and the  Am C Dm  cadence/turnaround does the trick very nicely.

Are there other Dorian modal folk songs that use a different cadence/turnaround?   It would be great to have a few different ones in the bag.

Comment: Im always surprised when people find a question to be worthy of an answer but not an up vote.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - I am, too, sometimes. The criteria for upvoting aren't necessarily the same for providing an answer, though.

Answer (score 3):

He's going to use notes not exactly from D minor, but D Dorian, a minor mode using the diatonic notes from key C. As you say, the leading note, C#, is unavailable, although there's a possibility he could flatten the D in blues fashion.

Even when playing in D minor, there's not always a C# present. Using the natural minor from its relative major of F, there's your C, but that will include Bb rather than Bnat.

As far as chords are concerned - since you'll be in a mode of C major, all the chords diatonic to that are useable: C Dm Em F G Am Bo, and their extensions (7ths etc.).

You can actually get away with him using Cnat against your A/A7/A9 chords,. Think about what happens in blues music - the 3rd is flattened often - so C against C# in an A chord will just sound bluesy.

Comment: Go on, embrace Dorian, rather than finding ways to make its 'wrong' notes fit the D minor you know and love!

Comment: @LaurencePayne - I'm happy with it, although it would seem so many more are happy with Dm. My proof of that would be comparison of the number of tunes written (or popular if you like!) in Dorian and minor (probably just natural?)

Comment: IN folk music, I wouldn't be surprised if Dorian won the contest!   In 'art' music from the Common Practice period, D minor (not so much the natural scale - CP really liked its dominant-tonic cadences with nice bright leading-notes) is king of course.

Answer (score 1):

The melodic minor would be D,E,F,G,A,B natural, C# and D(Ascending) and D, C,B bémol, A,G,F,E,D (Descending).

Since the 7th note (C) is not augmented, then you have Phrygian mode, by the end of which you have to declare your tonality. That means you have to play C# during the cadence.

Alternatively you can avoid Perfect Authentic Cadence and use Half Cadence in IV instead (I-IV) which not contains the 7th note

Comment: No.  That's D Melodic minor scale.

Comment: The melodic minor in classic harmony could be found with the definition "dorian". It is used to avoid the Triton in the Bass

Comment: That does not seem to be a common usage for _dorian_, but common usage would call that a melodic minor scale.

Comment: Indeed, as Laurence says, you've annotated the classical *melodic minor*. The Dorian mode on a common major scale/key will *not* have anything like that. In fact there is no Dorian that contains your quoted notes. D Dorian is DEFGADC. And whilst D melodic minor is DEFGABC# ascending, and DCBbAGFE descending (classical) that doesn't make it Dorian. Anything but ! And Phrygian doesn't come near!

Comment: When the 7th note of a minor scale is not augmented, we use Phrygian chord connections.

Comment: @VassilisDe -- What you say makes no sense to me; one of the most important notes characterizing Phrygian harmony is the ♭9, which is nowhere to be found in D E F G A B C or in D E F G A B C♯ or in D melodic minor or in D Dorian. What am I missing?